# model with user id laravel

Tags: php, model, laravel-4

I am developing an application where I want to get all of a user's open tasks and display them.  I have created a new view, route, controller and model, but I can't get the model to work right, especially as it pertains to getting the current user's ID for the SQL query.

app/models/Task.php

```
class Task extends Eloquent
{
    public static function open()
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;

        $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->where('c', 0)->where('user_id', $id)->get();

        return $tasks;
    }

}
```

Also

app/controllers/TaskController.php

```
public function open()
{
    $tasks = Task::open();

    return View::make('tasks.open')->with('tasks', $tasks);
}
```

**Error:** Trying to get property of non-object - looks like on the `$id = Auth::user()->id;`

What's the correct model?

Comment: What is not working right, any errors?

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" looks like on the "$id = Auth::user()->id;" line in the model.

Comment: I can only think of the user not being logged in?

Comment: `if (Auth::check())
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
}` start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not being logged in was the problem - this model works.

Because this will probably help someone else in the future: when you create a user's account, use Hash::make when you add the password to the database, because when you use Auth::attempt in your log in method, Laravel hashes password the user typed and compares the two, and if they're both not hashed, it won't log the user in.